# Crop an image to square using percentages and max widths

Tags: css, image, internet-explorer-8, crop

Working a responsive site, so I cannot use set widths.

I need pictures to all crop to square. I cannot define the exact measurements because it also needs to have `max-width:100%` in order to make it a responsive image which adjusts it's sized relative to the container (which is relative to the width of the browser).

I've seen a lot of solutions that suggest using `background-image` but this not possible, it must be an `img` tag. It also must work in IE8.

Any ideas?

I currently have:

```
.views-field-field-photo img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }



    <div class="field-content">
<img src="imagehere" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 25):

using `padding-bottom` along with positioning and `overflow:hidden` you can create a responsive square container:

```
.field-content{
    width:80%;
    padding-bottom:80%;
    margin:1em auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    background:#000
}

.field-content img {
   position:absolute;
   width:auto;
    min-width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/ecK7d/)

[jQuery DEMO center images when scaling](http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/ecK7d/3/)

I tidied up some of the js allowing multiple images to be scaled and put 4 images on a simple grid

Comment: This is great but is there a way to make it crop to centre rather than top right corner? Or at least top-center rather than top-left.

Comment: Only way I can think of is to throw some jquery at it - http://jsfiddle.net/duncan/ecK7d/2/ code is a bit messy but it does the job

Comment: You can crop from the center by doing the following:
.field-content img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

Answer (score -3):

You can do something like overflow:hidden
I've made a square of 100px you can define your own size.

HTML

```
<div id="frame">
<img src="your image"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#frame{
width:100px;
height:100px;
overflow:hidden;
}

#frame img{
width:auto;
height:100%;
min-width:100px;
min-height:100px;
}
```

Comment: This answer is a fixed width and is not responsive, op wanted responsive. @duncan-beattie has the answer for responsive above.