# How to crop boostrap image to get width 285 and height 170 of all images?

Tags: css, image, crop

I have difference size of images and I want it to have the same width and height and make it still responsive. So how to do this?

Comment: Hi! Your title says you want a fixed size, but in your question you say you want responsive size, which one is it? Do you want to crop the image to specific proportions? Please clarify.

Comment: @Josef Engelfrost I want it to responsive and also the same size.

Comment: so if you get this right you have images with different sizes and different proportions, but you want the images to have the same proportions (cropping away the overflow), and you want them to scale to the width of the container ("responsive")?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop an image to square using percentages and max widths](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689706/crop-an-image-to-square-using-percentages-and-max-widths)

Comment: I just want all the images to have the same height and responsive as I resize the screen.

Comment: Was my answer below helpful @leecleec ? vc é br?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you ever heard of **object-fit**?

The object-fit property defines how an element responds to the height and width of its content box. It's intended for images, videos and other embeddable media formats in conjunction with the object-position property. Used by itself, object-fit lets us crop an inline image by giving us fine-grained control over how it squishes and stretches inside its box.

Here's an example of what object-fit does to your image, and how it can be used: http://jsfiddle.net/8ba7zjhs/

HTML

```
<img class="niceImage" src="http://assets1.ignimgs.com/2013/09/17/trevorjpg-883566_1280w.jpg">
```

CSS

```
.niceImage {
    width: 385px;
    height: 140px;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
}
```

> Learn more about object-fit here:
>  **>** [css-tricks object-fit](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)
>   **>** [Mozilla object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

**Note:** All the browsers support object-fit nowadays except for Internet explorer, who is still considering to implement it as well.