# Can CSS make a grid of photos remain centered as numbers of rows are reduced?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Best to use the analogy of text aligned left but wanting it to align center instead.

I have a grid of twenty five 375px by 375px photos spanning 100% the width of the page I want to remain centered in all browsers and devices.
Obviously if the screen width is not a multiple of 375px I have blank space on the right. I want the blank space equal on both sides while maintaining the maximum number of rows from two to infinity. I want the photos to always be 375px by 375px.

I have tried

```
.container {
  width: 1140px;
  margin: auto;
}
.image {
  object-fit: cover;
  width:375px;
  height:375px;
  margin: -4px 0 0 0;
}
```

This obviously isn't responsive for all cases. I also tried using @media for each case and a few outlandish solutions from other Stack Overflow answers. I looked into npm packages and Reactstrap a little too with no luck.

[image: A visual aid just to reiterate the problem]

The images in React, (JSX. Not HTML)

```
  <div class="row">
    {Object.values(apiResponse).map((value, index) => 
    <a target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" href={value.post}>
      <img src={value.image} className="image"/>
    </a>)}
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using margin:0 auto on your container and make your container fit content instead of 100% width:

```
.container {
  max-width:1140px;
  min-width: 375px;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

The trick? `margin: 0 auto;` centers a block element horizontally on the page if it is smaller than the page. 0 is the top and bottom margin, auto is the left and right. Auto makes the left and right equal.

To use it in this case you also have to define a width other than 100% for the containing block element (div in OP's example, section in mine).

The same result could be achieved by defining the width still but giving the `body` element the style `text-align:center`. The downside to this is that it affects the whole page, not just this grid in OP's example.

Comment: I feel like an idiot saying this, but I'm using React and I only know how to write one style attribute. Like this `style={{"width": "fit-content"}}`. If I try to add another there doesn't seem to be an option.

Comment: The style in react is an object inside jsx tags, hence the double {. So in an object you can add more key/value pairs by separating them with commas :). Also React doesn't like dashes, so min-width becomes minWidth in React.

Comment: Taking it apart, it looks like `text-align:center` is the key, what do you call it "CSS options", "feature"? I never would have guessed. Is CSS kind of a mess? At least it's a simple solution compared to what I was looking at trying.

Comment: I believe margin 0 auto is the key. It centers the section horizontally. Text-align center centers the contents of the section within the section. And yes, CSS is a code unto itself IMO. It's fickle.

Comment: I put in a few @media's to make the last row shrink with the width. Pretty cool. `@media (min-width: 375px) {
  .image {object-fit: cover; width:375px; height:375px; margin: -4px 0 0 0;}
}
@media (max-width: 376px) {
  .image {object-fit: cover; width:100%; margin: -4px 0 0 0;}
}`

Comment: Agreed, `@media`s are super cool. Swap your two numbers 375 and 376; your media queries currently overlap by 1px :)

Comment: Someone gave you a down vote probably because you put the style in the element and not the CSS.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I was wondering what the issue was. I thought inline style was a simpler way to demonstrate my solution, I didn't realize SO doesn't like it.

Comment: Hello, Sydney. Thank you again for that answer, but I had to put the each <img> inside its own <div> for hover effects and now each image stacks vertically. It's one single column of all my photos stacked. The best I can do to bring the grid back is float left the div. That brings me the grid I want, but it's not centered anymore.

Comment: `div`s are automatically `display: block;` which makes them the only thing in a horizontal line. Did you try making each `div` 375px wide and `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: I didn't try that, but I'm stuck trying to solve a different problem with having images in a responsive grid with 100% width. Using `display: grid;grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;` for the container now. I tried applying this answer (link below). I know I'm outside of my OP and will have to ask a new question if I can't apply this answer. Haven't been able to so far. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16689706/crop-an-image-to-square-using-percentages-and-max-widths/16690595

Comment: I just spent 17 hours trying to make the image sizes responsive but came back to your answer div 375px wide and `display: inline-block;` Thank you once again. At this point I think making rectangle images square and responsive is impossible. Unless I get React to crop them somehow after loading. Thanks.